# How to dynamically change document title via function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document, title

I'd like to change document's title dynamically.

In the first instance I tried this snippet:

```
var milis = 3000,
    titles = [
      'Setting up color scheme'
    ], count = 0;
    titles.push(document.title);
    setInterval(function(){
      document.title = titles[count % titles.length];
      ++count;
    }, milis);
```

This works perfectly, but I need to put the snippet into a function so I can append titles at any time.

The function looks like this

```
function setUpTitle(){
    var milis = 3000;
    for(var i in arguments){
        titles = [
            arguments[i]
        ], count = 0;
        titles.push(document.title);
        setInterval(function(){
            document.title = titles[count % titles.length];
            ++count;
        }, milis);
    }
}

setUpTitle('one', 'two', 'three', ..., document.title);
```

But the title isn't changing at all.

How could I change it?

Comment: Try putting a semi colon after the titles array instead of a comma. "];"

Comment: it still doesn't work. I did this: `titles = [ arguments[i] ]; count = 0;` in that function

Comment: Okay how about changing for the loop to: for(var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i<j; i++) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var currentTitle = document.title;

var beginSubmission = setInterval(function(){
    loaded+=1;
    bar.css('width', loaded+'%');

    document.title = loaded+'% :: ' + currentTitle;

    text.empty().append(loaded + "% completed. <br>");
    if (loaded >= 100){
        clearInterval(beginSubmission);
        text.html('Done');
        document.title = currentTitle;
    }
}, time);
```

This backs up your title and changes the percentage on it. At the end, put the original title back on the page.

Also, remove this:

```
        var milis = 3000,
        titles = [
            'Setting up color scheme'
        ], count = 0;
        titles.push(document.title);
        title = setInterval(function(){
            document.title = titles[count % titles.length];
            ++count;
        }, milis);
```

Or replace to just this:

```
document.title = 'Setting up color scheme';
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you're overwriting your variables. Try this:

```
function setUpTitle(){
    var milis = 1000;
    var titles = [document.title];
    var count = 0;
    for(var i in arguments){
        titles.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    setInterval(function(){
        document.title = titles[count % titles.length];
        ++count;
    }, milis);
}

setUpTitle('one', 'two');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/otow2fg8/1/

Comment: first time when enters in loop, it shows last but one item, in our case: one ( one, page's title > two, one, page's title > two, one ... )

Comment: Please explain what do you mean? It should go like:
title -> one -> two -> title -> one -> two -> ...
Try with my edited answer.

Comment: I mean that it goes: one -> title -> two -> one -> title -> (and keeps repeating two -> one -> title) ->... I tried! This is what I get.

Comment: IMO you've copied the setInterval() function to your for() loop. It should be outside. Please check.

Comment: modified, it's perfect now!

Comment: what I still don't understand though, is that I want to put progress on title, so I did: `if (loaded >= 100){ ... } else { setUpTitle(loaded); }`, title changes after 8 seconds, and it takes very fast new values: title > (after 8s) 1 > (after 500ms) title > (after 500 ms) 8 > 2, 3, (without title from now) 5, 18, 2, 3, 36

Comment: It is because you are repeating the main setInterval() function mutliple times, so it fires up like more and more times. To prevent it you first have to stop it! You can do this like that:
var intervalFunction;
function setUpTitle(){
... 
intervalFunction = setInterval(function() {
...
}
}
Then, before running the function again, you will have to clear interval by adding:
clearInterval(intervalFunction);
before calling the main function.

Comment: well, I tried. I have a call to function in `beforeSend`, then after `if(loaded>=100) {...}` it clears the interval while the progress runs, and shows "(100%) > title" ... after progress has been completed, I don't want this. All I want is to show progress while it's in progress then to clear interval.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what's the goal. Please provide us a JsFiddle, to see what's wrong and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change document title in jsfiddle. So I have a progress from 0 to 100% in 15 seconds, in this time, I want title to change with: the progress value > default title

Comment: Try it like that: `document.title = (count % 2) ? originalTitle : getProgressValue();`.